# How to prove $\frac{1+a^2+a^4+\cdots+a^{2n}}{a+a^3+\cdots+a^{2n-1}}>\frac{n+1}{n}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$a$ is positive and $a\neq 1$, I want to prove
$$\frac{1+a^2+a^4+\cdots+a^{2n}}{a+a^3+\cdots+a^{2n-1}}> \frac{n+1}{n}$$
I tried the induction method, but I didn't work out the case for $n=2$
$$\frac{1+a^2+a^4}{a+a^3}>\frac{3}{2}\Leftrightarrow 1+a^2+a^4> \frac{3}{2}a+\frac{3}{2}a^3$$
I try to use relation $A^2+B^2\geq 2AB$, but I failed to get the correct coefficient,
$$1+\frac{9}{16}a^2> \frac{3}{2}a,  
 \frac{9}{16}a^2+a^4> \frac{3}{2}a^3$$
Is there any way to fix this? I guess I used the wrong formula  $A^2+B^2\geq 2AB$.

Comment: It might help to simplify the left-hand side with the geometric sum formula.

Comment: You like to prove $$
f(a): = \frac{{a^{2n + 2}  - 1}}{{a(a^{2n}  - 1)}} > \frac{{n + 1}}{n}
$$ for $a>0$, $a\neq 1$. Show that $f'(a)<0$ for $0<a<1$ and $f'(a)>0$ for $a>1$. Compute $\lim_{a\to 1}f(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the $n = 2$ case, observe that $2 - 3a + 2a^2 - 3a^3 + 2a^4 = (a-1)^2 ( 2a^2 + a + 2)$, hence is always positive.

---

For the induction step, we  WTS
$$ 1 - a + a^2 - a^3 + \ldots + a^{2k} - (k+2)a^{2k+1} +( k+1) a^{2k+2} > 0.$$
This is true because it can be factored as $(a-1)( (k+1) a^{2k+1} - a^{2k} - a^{2k-2} - a^{2k-4} - \ldots - 1) $.
Consider each $a^{2k+1} - a^{2i} = (a-1) \times f_i (a)$, where $f_i(a)$ is a polynomial with positive coefficients.
Hence, the expression is $ (a-1)^2 \times \sum f_i (a)$, which is positive.

---

In fact, the idea of factoring out $(a-1)^2$ in the general case is directly:

$$n(1 + a^2 + \ldots + a^{2n} ) - (n+1) (a + a^3 + \ldots + a^{2n-1})  $$
$$= (a-1)^2 (1\times n a^{2n-2}  + 1\times (n-1)a^{2n-3} + 2 \times (n-1) a^{2n-4} + 2 \times (n-2) a^{2n-5} + 3\times (n-2) a^{2n-5} - \ldots + n\times 1 a^0) $$

To see the pattern of the quotient, observe that every other coefficient is of the form $i \times (k-i)$ where $k = n+1$ or $n$.

---

Alternative solution for the general case:

- Using the formula for GP, show that the inequality is equivalent to
  $$ \frac{ a^{2n+2} - 1 } { a(a^{2n} - 1 ) }  > \frac{ n+1}{n}.$$
- If $ a > 1$, we want to show that
  $ n a^{2n+2} +(n+1)a  - (n+1) a^{2n+1}  - n >0 $.

  - This can be factorized as $(a-1) ( na^{2n+1} - a^{2n} - \ldots - a^2 - a      +n) > 0 $.
  - The first term is positive.
  - The second term is positive as $ a^{2n+1} - a^{2n+1 - i} - a^i + 1 = ( a^{2n+1-i} - 1 ) ( a^{i} - 1 ) > 0$
- If $ a < 1$, we want to show that $ n a^{2n+2} +(n+1)a  - (n+1) a^{2n+1}  - n < 0 $.

  - Again, this can be factorized as $(a-1) ( na^{2n+1} - a^{2n} - \ldots - a^2 - a      +n) < 0 $.
  - The first term is negative.
  - The second term is positive as $ a^{2n+1} - a^{2n+1 - i} - a^i + 1 = ( a^{2n+1-i} - 1 ) ( a^{i} - 1 ) > 0 $

Note

- This was my first approach.
- It is essentially the same as the factoring of $(a-1)^2$, but we didn't need to figure out exactly how to factorize it.

Comment: One can also notice that the given inequality is invariant under the transformation $a \mapsto 1/a$, so that it suffices to consider the case $a > 1$.

Comment: @MartinR Note that this holds even for negative $a$. Though that also follows by using the transformation $ a \mapsto -a$ since the denominator is smaller and the numerator is the same.

Answer (score 2):

$1+a^2+a^4> \frac{3}{2}a+\frac{3}{2}a^3\iff (1-a)^2+a^2(1-a)^2-\frac 12a(1-a)^2\gt 0\iff (1-a)^4+\frac 32a(1-a)^2 \gt 0$

Answer (score -2):

Multiply both sides by the denominators to get $n(1 + a^2 + a^4 + \cdots + a^{2n}) > (n+1)(a + a^3 + \cdots + a^{2n - 1})$

Now move the multiples of n all to the left hand side: $n(1 - a + a^2 - a^3 + a^4 + \cdots - a^{2n - 1} + a^{2n}) > a + a^3 + \cdots + a^{2n - 1}$

Now, as long as n is positive then then LHS is clearly positive since for every negative term in the polynomial there is a larger positive term.

Consider the difference $a^x - a^{x - 1} = a^{x - 1}(a - 1)$ for all x. Then we can simplify the equation to:

$n(1 + a(a - 1) + a^3(a - 1) + \cdots + a^{2n - 1}(a - 1)) > a + a^3 + \cdots + a^{2n - 1}$

Simplify:

$n + n(a - 1)(a + a^3 + \cdots + a^{2n - 1}) > a + a^3 + \cdots + a^{2n - 1}$

If $n \geq 1$ and $a \geq 2$, then trivially the above equality is true.

If $0 < n < 1$, then the result maybe true or false depending upon the specific values - but it doesn’t hold generally.

Similarly, if $1 < a < 2$, then the equality may or may not be true in a specific case - but is not true generally since multiplying by $(a - 1)$ will scale down $(a + a^3 + \cdots)$, approaching 0 for sufficiently small a.

If $n \leq 0$, on the other hand, then it would appear to always be false since the LHS will be negative while the RHS will be positive.

Conclusion: the inequality does not hold over the reals, but may hold true over a reduced domain depending upon the value of a.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why "trivially the above equality is true"?

Comment: @CalvinLin since a is greater than 1, then $(a + a^3 + \cdots)$ is positive. However, I did not consider the cases where either 1 < a < 2 or 0 < x < 1. If a or x are sufficiently small then it could in fact be less than the RHS. I will edit to account for this.

Comment: I think everything is correct now, though my answer is significantly different from the others :P

Comment: Your statements are correct, but the solution is incomplete (and it's not immediately clear to me if there is a way to proceed using your ideas).   $\quad$ FWIW I'm assuming that $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @CalvinLin as long as the above is all correct then I think we’ve shown the equality to be false over the reals, but true over a reduced domain. The OP would need to clarify further constraints if they exist.

Comment: How did you show the inequality is true for say $ a = 1.1$? You stated "may or may not be true in a specific case" (which is a correct statement for what you have so far).

Comment: The above shows the inequality could be true or false for a=1.1 depending upon the value of n

Comment: We are required to show that the inequality is true for $a  = 1.1$ (and positive integer $n$), which it is. You cannot just show it is true on a subset of the given domain and claim ignorance on the rest of the domain, then state that you've solved to problem.

Comment: I don’t claim ignorance. I claim that the inequality does not generally hold true over the reals. Just because it wasn’t the desired result doesn’t mean it’s not correct

Comment: Let's agree to disagree, and we've made our opinions clear. I'm bowing out of this exchange.